# An intuition connected with Heyting implication

Tags: boolean-algebra, lattice-orders, constructive-mathematics, intuitionistic-logic

Suppose $L$ is a bounded lattice and let $\Rightarrow$ be its Heyting implication, i.e. the operation defined in the standard way: $x\Rightarrow y$ is the largest object of the set $\{u\in L\mid u\cdot x\leqslant y\}$.

I have a slight problem with thinking about $x\Rightarrow y\leqslant y$ in general case. If, for example, $L$ is a Boolean algebra, then $x\Rightarrow y=-x+y$, so 
$$x\Rightarrow y\leqslant y\longleftrightarrow-x+y\leqslant y\longleftrightarrow-x\leqslant y$$
and this can be easily interpreted in a field of sets.

Could you please give me a hint how to think about $x\Rightarrow y\leqslant y$?

Comment: But $x \to y \leq y$ is not valid in general. It is only valid if it is equal, because $y \leq x \to y$ is valid, as it follows from $x \wedge y \leq y$ and thus $y \in \{ z \in L : x \wedge z \leq y \}$, whence $y \leq \max\{ z \in L : x \wedge z \leq y\} = x \to y$.

Comment: It is not, you are right. But my question does not  concern validity.

Comment: Then I think that a correct interpretation of $y \leq x \to y$ is that if $y$ is true, then $x \to y$ is also true, even if $x$ is not. And this is valid in intuitionistic logic (but not in relevance logic, for example).

Comment: I agree with this, yet my question concerns the reverse situation: $x\Rightarrow y\leqslant y$ :)